# Angular Material Tab is not being highlighted

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to programmatically set the selected index and it works fine, thanks to the `[(selectedIndex)]=""`, but whenever I select index with this, there is no highlight on the selected item.

It is selected because you can see the content of it, but there is no graphical representation of selected tab state.
Is this a bug or it can be done somehow?

Html

```
 <mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="this.dataService.selectedTabs[0]">
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let Tab of this.dataService.Tabs">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      {{Tab.label}}
    </ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="Tab.childTabs.length !== 0">
     //INSIDE OF THIS SECTION THERE ARE MORE NESTED TABS
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

And when I open this tab, nested tabs within its content won't be highlighted but they are opened.

Ts

```
public selectedTabs: any[] = [
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
];
```

Comment: show some ts code

Comment: @AlleXyS ok done

Comment: Please show your full dataService code.

Answer (score 3):

This solution works but it is mainly a workaround. 
Just add this code in the ***style.css*** file:

```
.mat-tab-label-active {
bottom-border-style:solid !important;
opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Here I used border-bottom-style instead of bottom-border-style.